# Change major axis grid line intervals in MSchart for R

Tags: r, mschart

I'm using the mschart library in R to create a scatter plot.  I want to adjust the interval between the major grid lines.  For example, in the image below I would like to set the x axis interval to 0 by 20 to 100 and the y axis interval to 0 to 300 by 100.  Is there anyway to do this mschart or do I have to adjust the chart manually?

[image]

Here is the code that generated the chart.  I was expecting to see a major grid interval or breaks argument in chart_ax_x but there is only arguments for the axis limits.

```
library(mschart)
n <- 1e3
sigma <- 10
x <- 100*rbeta(n, 3, 4 )
y <- 100 + x + rnorm(n,0, 20)

plot(x, y)


dta <- data.frame(x, y)
dta

sp <- mschart::ms_scatterchart(dta, 'x', 'y')
sp <- mschart::chart_data_size(sp, values = 4) 
sp <- mschart::chart_ax_x(sp, limit_min = 0, limit_max =100)
sp <- mschart::chart_ax_y(sp, limit_min = 0, limit_max =300)

print(sp, preview = TRUE)
```

Comment: the plot is shown in powerpoint ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need it to be rendered using `mschart`? The documentation [here](https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/charts-with-mschart.html#customise-charts) does not detail any options to modify axis intervals, only the aesthetics of gridlines and ticks etc. Looks like you'll have to edit them manually, or you could try using `ggplot2` and save the output as an svg if you need your chart to be a vector-based file. Or a jpg or png would also work if it doesn't have to be a vector file.

Comment: Thank you @LeroyTyrone.  Our stakeholders are familiar with excel aesthetics so I would like to keep that style, but I may try using theme_excel_new in ggplot2.  The only disadvantage is that most of the final people reviewing the document know Excel but not R.  So if they have to make any last minute changes to the plots, they'll have to ask me to rerun the R program rather than being able to directly edit the plots themselves.

Comment: Ah, yes. You could potentially use a VBA macro in Excel to automate the modification of axis intervals. Kinda depends on how often you need modify charts, and/or how variable the outputs are. Lots of examples on the www for how to do it if you're not familiar with macros.